# gem hub not found after ruby upgrade

Tags: ruby, github, rbenv

I updated my ruby version to 2.4.4

I am trying to run hub create, but I got the following error:

```
rbenv: hub: command not found

The `hub' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.3.5
```

I have seen that I have like two gems of hub (or paths) in my computer:

```
which -a hub
/Users/albertmontolio/.rbenv/shims/hub
/usr/local/bin/hub
```

I read that I have to uninstall one, so I've done:

```
gem uninstall -x hub
```

But still I see the two paths and the error: hub command not found is still there.

Why I can not use the gem hub and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: i didn't realize `hub` was a ruby gem; how i always do it is go to their [releases](https://github.com/github/hub/releases) page, download an executable, and run it directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Ruby version has a different gem path, so just reinstall hub under Ruby 2.4.4 using `gem install hub` or delete the shim at `~/.rbenv/shims/hub`, so that it uses the copy in `/usr/local/bin/hub` (likely installed with homebrew).